# Debezium Sink Connector. How to add to downstream table new data from cdc column

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I use Debezium to stream data from MySQL to PostgreSQL.
I need in PostgreSQL column(smt like data_changed or new_data_cdc) which reflect whenever update/insert occurs from CDC field changes.

This fields means that new data come from CDC and another task will process it.

What I found:

1. I can use "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.type.Type" to manually operate default value but haven't found any suitable example
2. Also I try to use triggers(I try to avoid triggers). Smths like

`create or replace function after_each_statement_on_the_table() returns trigger language plpgsql...`

3. I can manipulate Kafka transformation .
   from this https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/configuration/event-flattening.html

`transforms=unwrap,...  transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState  transforms.unwrap.add.fields=op,table,lsn,source.ts_ms`

That will add  "__lsn": "123456789"
On __lsn I can build index and manipulate.

Finally I want smt's like this:

Column "new_data_from_cdc": 1 - data new and should be processed; 0 - data is processed by service

If nothing helps i will use Kafka transformation and trigger on __lsn or __source_ts_ms